# How to serve a site from different host

Tags: cloud, hosting

Let's say 123.com
I host it on cloudways

But I want to serve 123.com/test from Google cloud, how do I go about this?

Basically I have a site hosted on cloudways and is want to serve a single page from a different web host

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Engine is already available on Cloudways so you can deploy your website on GCE using Cloudways Platform.

Or if you want to choose two different cloud hosting providers for your web application, Cloudways is already offering 5 different IAAS services, so you can deploy other parts of the website into other cloud hosting by launching a new server.

I hope this helps, but please let me know if you need anything else or if you have any other questions.